# Websites takes some seconds to start loading sporadically - resolve hostname - DNS issue?

Tags: networking, dns

I opened another thread here some weeks ago [Internet sites are loading slowly sometimes with Firefox and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276481/internet-sites-are-loading-slowly-sometimes-with-firefox-and-chromium).

The solution helped to improve the loading speed in general, but I still have the (minor) issue that sporadically websites take some seconds to start loading. In chromium I then see the message "Resolve Host" (Host auflösen in German) on the left bottom. That's why I think it could be due a DNS issue, but all tests we did in the other thread show that everything seems to be fine. I tried the Ubuntustudio live image and it seems to work without issues there, although I only could test it with Firefox which is not showing me that message.

My PC is connected via LAN to a Fritzbox repeater (1750E) and that one is connected by WLAN to another one which finally connects to the Fritzbox by WLAN. All routers are meshed and all my other devices works fine.

The issue occurs more often after diretly starting the PC. If website A has problems with resolving the host name and it finally loads after some seconds, the second time I load the site it works immediately which may be points to a DNS cache issue (?). I even get it sometimes when opening my router fritz.box site.

My Ubuntu version is:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Some more info:

```
    System:
      Host: marco-MS-7817 Kernel: 5.4.0-47-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 
      Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
    Machine:
      Type: Desktop Mobo: MSI model: H81M-E34 (MS-7817) v: 3.0 
      serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 17.5 
      date: 03/30/2015 
    CPU:
      Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4460 bits: 64 type: MCP 
      L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
      Speed: 3200 MHz min/max: 800/3200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3200 2: 3200 
      3: 3200 4: 3200 
    Graphics:
      Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics 
      driver: i915 v: kernel 
      Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
      resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
      OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) 
      v: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.8 
    Audio:
      Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio 
      driver: snd_hda_intel 
      Device-2: BEHRINGER UMC204HD 192k type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio 
      Device-3: AKAI Professional M.I. type: USB 
      driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
      Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-47-lowlatency 
    Network:
      Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
      driver: r8169 
      IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99 
    Drives:
      Local Storage: total: 523.08 GiB used: 159.23 GiB (30.4%) 
      ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 250GB size: 232.89 GiB 
      ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Samsung model: Portable SSD T5 
      size: 232.89 GiB 
      ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra size: 57.30 GiB 
    Partition:
      ID-1: / size: 36.41 GiB used: 12.45 GiB (34.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
      ID-2: /home size: 184.23 GiB used: 66.59 GiB (36.1%) fs: ext4 
      dev: /dev/sda6 
      ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.45 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
    Sensors:
      System Temperatures: cpu: 41.0 C mobo: N/A 
      Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
    Info:
      Processes: 260 Uptime: 20m Memory: 7.23 GiB used: 3.97 GiB (54.9%) 
      Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38 


edit:

     sudo lshw -C network
    [sudo] Passwort für marco: 
      *-network                 
           Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
           Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           Physische ID: 0
           Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
           Logischer Name: enp2s0
           Version: 0c
           Seriennummer: d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99
           Größe: 1Gbit/s
           Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
           Breite: 64 bits
           Takt: 33MHz
           Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.178.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
           Ressourcen: irq:18 ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff

    ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.178.23/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
           valid_lft 862605sec preferred_lft 862605sec


  


  
-------------------------------------------------------------
@tracepath


    tracepath www.google.com
     1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1492
     1:  fritz.box                                             7.938ms 
     1:  wpad.fritz.box                                        1.830ms 
     2:  x4db53c5a.dyn.telefonica.de                           2.639ms pmtu 1492
     2:  loopback1.0003.acln.02.fra.de.net.telefonica.de      14.828ms 
     3:  bundle-ether30.0004.dbrx.02.fra.de.net.telefonica.de  16.144ms 
     4:  bundle-ether1.0004.prrx.02.fra.de.net.telefonica.de  15.519ms 
     5:  72.14.213.76                                         16.803ms asymm 10 
     6:  keine Antwort
     7:  keine Antwort
     8:  keine Antwort
     9:  keine Antwort
    10:  keine Antwort
    11:  keine Antwort
    12:  keine Antwort
    13:  keine Antwort
    14:  keine Antwort
    15:  keine Antwort
    16:  keine Antwort
    17:  keine Antwort
    18:  keine Antwort
    19:  keine Antwort
    20:  keine Antwort
    21:  keine Antwort
    22:  keine Antwort
    23:  keine Antwort
    24:  keine Antwort
    25:  keine Antwort
    26:  keine Antwort
    27:  keine Antwort
    28:  keine Antwort
    29:  keine Antwort
    30:  keine Antwort
         Too many hops: pmtu 1492
         Resume: pmtu 1492 

--------------------------------------------------

    systemd-resolve --status
    Global
           LLMNR setting: no                  
    MulticastDNS setting: no                  
      DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
          DNSSEC setting: no                  
        DNSSEC supported: no                  
              DNS Domain: fritz.box           
              DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                          16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          168.192.in-addr.arpa
                          17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          corp                
                          d.f.ip6.arpa        
                          home                
                          internal            
                          intranet            
                          lan                 
                          local               
                          private             
                          test                
    
    Link 2 (enp2s0)
          Current Scopes: DNS          
    DefaultRoute setting: yes          
           LLMNR setting: yes          
    MulticastDNS setting: no           
      DNSOverTLS setting: no           
          DNSSEC setting: no           
        DNSSEC supported: no           
      Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1
             DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1
              DNS Domain: ~.           
                          fritz.box    
    lines 25-47/47 (END)
                          31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                          corp                
                          d.f.ip6.arpa        
                          home                
                          internal            
                          intranet            
                          lan                 
                          local               
                          private             
                          test                
    
    Link 2 (enp2s0)
          Current Scopes: DNS          
    DefaultRoute setting: yes          
           LLMNR setting: yes          
    MulticastDNS setting: no           
      DNSOverTLS setting: no           
          DNSSEC setting: no           
        DNSSEC supported: no           
      Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1
             DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1
              DNS Domain: ~.           
                          fritz.box    
    ~

    ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 27 22:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

   

     cat /etc/resolv.conf
    # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
    # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
    # run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
    
    nameserver 127.0.0.53
    search fritz.box




    dpkg -l *dnsmasq* | grep ii
    ii  dnsmasq-base     2.80-1.1ubuntu1 amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
```

Comment: in my opinion you need more info to understand where is the problem. I suggest you to install [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/load-time/)  for firefox that will tell you the time spent over the steps to load a page. For example connection time, dns resolv time, parsing html time and so on. If you don't like there is also [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/page-performance-test/). 

And [this is a screenshot](https://ibb.co/MZVc4Gy)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for such a tool and I'm the same opinion as you.

Comment: Don't know if that helps, but "time to first byte" took 10s here: https://imgur.com/LmgF5FD.png

Comment: @Lews : When it takes long to load I get large values for DNS lookup (5s, 10s, etc.). Sometimes also long DOM Processing times, but I guess that's due to the website and no issue on my site. I tried the Live image again and I don't have any issues when using the live image.

Comment: I still don't have any solution for this. Sometimes when visiting new web pages after the computer was booted resolving the host takes some seconds.

Comment: I'd try changing dns and I'd try to boot from a linux livecd if the problem disappear. If you have the same problem on livecd the problem is the router or the provider.

Comment: @Lews: The times I checked the LiveCD it was working fine, but I make longer test to be sure. Changing DNS didn't  help, already tried this.

Comment: I forgot that the problem could be even hardware, maybe the network interface, then you should try also with an other device+livecd.

Comment: It started when I switched from Debian to Ubuntu, that's why I think it might be configuration related. And it happens rarely and not reproducible. Could it be a problem with dnsmasq?

Comment: I don't think so. You shoult investigate with hints I gave you and also try to look in the logs. If it's a browser rendering problem maybe a permission issue.. for example apparmor. Also you can try to rename the .mozilla directory and start a new clean instance of firefox. If the problem persist I'd try to create a new user and try to navigate internet from the clean and new user.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the live version once more. It happens also with Chromium where I see the message "Resolve Host" on the left bottom side. I also installed the performace analyzer plugin and if that occurs I see rather long times  for DNS. All other devices in the network are working. It's hard to figure it out. It also happens quite often when I connect to my fritz.box settings page via the browser (address is "fritz.box"). As my fritz box site is not a common website does that help maybe?

Comment: Now it happend again on bandcamp. The host resolve message appeared. But due to performance analyzer at least in this case on the DNS site it seems to be fine: https://imgur.com/bl1AaCe.png (18 ms) . The yellow bar is Cross-Domain Redirect (and/or other Delay) and that took quite long.

Comment: I did some tests with a WLAN stick from ASUS during the last two weeks. While surfing with WLAN the issue did not happen. Only one time the DNS resolving took ~1s, beside of that it was always fine. The stick connected to the same repeater which I used for LAN connection. So, I assume that the problem is related to the LAN adapter of my motherboard or to the driver for this adapter (Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169). I think I'll order a USB LAN adapter to be 100 % sure.

Comment: Back to the LAN adapter on my Motherboard and issues are back. Most of the time the DNS lookup time is exactly 5.01 s. According to this site https://www.math.tamu.edu/~comech/tools/linux-slow-dns-lookup/ I disabled IP6, but this didn't help.